# How to generate model without require module loader with JavaScript Swagger Codegen?

Tags: ecmascript-6, model, swagger-codegen

I am generating model in JavaScript with `-Dmodels` option. The generated code contains `require` module loader used in Node, but I am using Vue Js.
So, I have problem when I require these files in Vue Js project. It gives me an error about `superagent` - it suppose I will use `superagent` which is also autogenerated. 
What I want is to generate pure models with ES6 export/import statements. Is it possible with [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#compatibility) or should I use something else?
Currently, I am using [openapi-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-client) but there is no support for model generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, like it usually happens - you find your answer after you ask a question :)
I found there is an option `--additional-properties` you can provide like:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate   -i path-to-your-file.yaml   -l javascript --additional-properties useES6=true
```

You can list all available options with the following command:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l javascript
```